# attachShadow vs createShadowRoot

Tags: shadow-dom

I read in mozilla doc, [Element.createShadowRoot()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/createShadowRoot) is deprecated:

> This method has been deprecated in favor of attachShadow.

But in my canary: chrome 49.0.2599.0

thats work:

```
 var shadow = document.getElementById("node-sh").createShadowRoot();
```

And thats not work

```
 var shadow = document.getElementById("node-sh").attachShadow({mode: 'closed'});
```

Anyone know what's right?

Answer (score 17):

`createShadowRoot()` is the old way of attaching a shadow-root to host element. It was proposed in initial spec, which has then been deprecated in favor of 
 `attachShadow`. 
Spec also has been [updated](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/commit/fc96d253e91293858a1ad7c53f39eedc5a48b37f).

But, new API hasn't been standardized and **none** of the browsers currently support it. So I would suggest to stick to `createShadowRoot`for now. Once you start getting browser warnings for deprecation, that would be the time to move to `attachShadow`.

Comment: Perfect, ty Abhinav.

Comment: @user2225055 Well, you can mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem, to help other developers who stumble upon this question. :)