# What is the alternative for Element.createShadowRoot()?

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm using this piece of code:

```
function setShadowDOM(i, css){
    [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName(i), function(hostVal) {
        var _root = hostVal.createShadowRoot();
            _root.innerHTML = '<style>:host ' + css + '</style><content></content>';
    })
}
```

I'm also [**reading this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/createShadowRoot).

How to solve this? What would be the alternative?

Comment: From `mdn`: `This method has been deprecated in favor of attachShadow.`, and this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452028/atachshadow-vs-createshadowroot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now you can use `attachShadow()` instead of `createShadowRoot()`:

- **It is [implemented](http://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdomv1)** natively in Chrome (53+), Opera (40+), Safari (10+), and Firefox (63+).
- There's also **a [polyfill](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/shadowdom/?hl=en#historysupport)** by the webcomponents.js team: [ShadyDOM](https://github.com/webcomponents/shadydom).

The Shadow DOM v1 is a [DOM Living Standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#shadow-trees).

Edge will soon adopt the Chromium engine, then it will be Shadow DOM v1 compliant.

Answer (score 1):

The [**MDN docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/createShadowRoot) tell to you to use [**`attachShadow`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow) instead... but that feature is itself flagged as non-standard and totally unsupported by any browser at the moment :

[image]

[image]

Until there's a standard that has decent browser support, it's best to use [**webcomponents.js**](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/) (which acts as a [**polyfill**](https://remysharp.com/what-is-a-polyfill/)) or [**Polymer**](https://www.polymer-project.org/) (which has its own API) if you want to use web components.

As even [**webcomponents.js**](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/) doesn't support `attachShadow`, your options at the moment are either to :

- keep using [**`Element.createShadowRoot()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/createShadowRoot) and use [**webcomponents.js**](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/) for polyfilling this feature in unsupported browsers

... or to :

- port your web components to [**Polymer**](https://www.polymer-project.org/) (which means you should use Polymer's API instead)

Many people prefer [**Polymer**](https://www.polymer-project.org/) to [**webcomponents.js**](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/), precisely because it has its own API. If you use  [**Polymer**](https://www.polymer-project.org/), your code is more likely to be future-proof, because the exact web component implementation takes place under the hood and any changes to that implementation are less likely to impact Polymer's own API.